# Why matplotlib circle/patchCollection's point of rotation get changed

Tags: python, matplotlib

3 different rotation degree:

[image]

Hi, I am trying to rotate Matplotlib Collections.PatchCollection (circles). I could not keep the same point of rotation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib as mpl
 
num = 5
sizes = 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01
xy = (.5,.7),(.5,.6),(.5,.5),(.5,.4),(.5,.3)


print(xy)

 
 # Note that the patches won't be added to the axes, instead a collection will
patches = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
patches2 = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
 
coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, facecolors='none')
coll2 = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches2, facecolors='None')
ax.add_collection(coll)
ax.add_collection(coll2)

t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(12.5) + ax.transData
coll2.set_transform(t2)



plt.show()
```

How to keep the same point of rotation after rotation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like it *is* using the same point of rotation each time: (0,0) (the bottom left corner)

Comment: If I am not wrong, It is better to use <rotate_deg_around> than  <rotate_deg> for Collections.PatchCollection/Circle as r-beginners said

Comment: I certainly agree! I was just disputing your text and diagram that says the point of rotation is different each time (your green arrows). Actually the point of rotation is the same each time (your green arrows are all in the wrong place: they should point to where the axes cross in the bottom left). It's just not the rotation point you desire. Yes, the fix is to use `rotate_deg_around()` if you want to rotate around a different point.

Answer (score 4):

To rotate it, it seems to be specified with `.rotate_deg_around(x,y,degree)`.
This example is rotated 90 degrees at xy=0.5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib as mpl
 
num = 5
sizes = 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01
xy = (.5,.7),(.5,.6),(.5,.5),(.5,.4),(.5,.3)

print(xy)
 
 # Note that the patches won't be added to the axes, instead a collection will
patches = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
patches2 = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
 
coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, facecolors='none')
coll2 = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches2, facecolors='None')
ax.add_collection(coll)
ax.add_collection(coll2)
coords = [0.5,0.5]
# t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(12.5) + ax.transData
# t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(2.5) + ax.transData
t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0], coords[1], 90) + ax.transData
coll2.set_transform(t2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a center of rotation, the rotation will be around (0,0). To rotate around a certain point, you can first subtract its coordinates, do the rotation and then add these coordinates again.

The following example shows the difference:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib as mpl

sizes = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
xy = [(.5, .7), (.5, .6), (.5, .5), (.5, .4), (.5, .3)]
xc, yc = xy[-1]  # (.5, .3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
for ax in axes:
    patches = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
    coll = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches, facecolors='none')
    ax.add_collection(coll)
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
    for angle in np.arange(12.5, 360, 12.5):
        patches2 = [plt.Circle(center, size) for center, size in zip(xy, sizes)]
        coll2 = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches2, facecolors=cmap(angle / 360))
        if ax == axes[0]:
            t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(angle) + ax.transData
            ax.set_title('rotation around (0, 0)')
        else:
            t2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().translate(-xc, -yc).rotate_deg(angle).translate(xc, yc) + ax.transData
            ax.set_title(f'rotation around {xc, yc}')
        coll2.set_transform(t2)
        ax.add_collection(coll2)
    ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]